# Link two tables to the grid view c#

Tags: c#, database

Friends,

I have 2 tables in my database called "Children " and "Funds" .

children's table contains "CID, Fname, Lname,.. etc".

Funds table contains "CID, Date, Fund.. etc.

My problem is I need to show "CID, 
Full name (Fname + Lname) ,Date, Fund"
In my Data grid view.
 How can I do it friends?

Im using c# service based data base

Comment: Do you mean the EntityFramwork with "c# service based Database"?

Comment: No. Friend just sql sever service based db.

Comment: You can either have the `JOIN`in your database query or you could have a DataView if you are using a DataSet bound to your GridView. You'd have to tell more about your current implementation to get a specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

So assume that we have two classes bellow

```
public class Children {
    public string CID {get; set;}
    public string Lname {get; set;}
    public string Fname {get; set;}

}
public class Fund {
    public string CID {get; set;}
    public string Date {get; set;}
    public string Fund {get; set;}

}
```

Then in the your main function you have 2 list of these class above:

```
List<Children> Childrens; // It can be Ienumable also
List<Fund> Funds;
```

And finally we are using linq to join two list

```
var Lst = from child in Childrens join fund in Funds on child.CID equals 
            fund.CID select new {CID = child.child, 
            FullNam = child.Lname + " " + child.Fname, fund.Date, fund.Fund};
```

You have the list name "Lst" and the final step adds its value to the datagridview